# How can I take numerator of an expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

How can I take numerator of the expressions?
[image]

```
-((2 (r^2) )/E) + (2 a)/E^3 + r \[Lambda] == 
  0 && -2 r^2 Subscript[a, 1] + (6 Subscript[a, 1])/E^2 == 0
```

Comment: Have your tried [`Numerator`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Numerator.html) ?

Comment: Yes, I did. But it doesn't work for this example. Or I can't.

Comment: You may need to apply `Together` first.  For example, `eqns = -((2 (r^2))/E) + (2 a)/E^3 + r \[Lambda] == 0 && -2 r^2 Subscript[a, 1] + (6 Subscript[a, 1])/E^2 == 0;
Together@eqns  /. x_ == 0 :> Numerator[x] == 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "12.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Format[a1] = Subscript["a", 1];

expr = -((2 (r^2))/E) + (2 a)/E^3 + r λ == 0 &&
   -2 r^2 a1 + (6 a1)/E^2 == 0;
```

Since the denominators are numeric constants, [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) will do what is probably wanted.

```
expr2 = expr // FullSimplify
```

[image]

Using [`Numerator`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Numerator.html) gives equivalent results

```
Map[Numerator, expr // Together, {2}]
```

[image]